# Olá, pessoal! sou novato em Banco de Dados e tenho uma dúvida no Sql Managent Studio. Como faço para sair daqui e prosseguir?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

[image: O QUE ADICIONO NO CAMPO 'NOME DO SERVIDOR'?]

O QUE ADICIONO NO CAMPO 'NOME DO SERVIDOR'?

Comment: O nome da instância/servidor que você quer se conectar, por exemplo: *computador\SQLExpress*. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/f1-help/connect-to-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15. Recomendo a leitura: http://www.macoratti.net/vbn_ssms.htm

Comment: Pode colocar o nome da sua máquina.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!
Essa tela, é a tela padrão de login para conectar ao banco de dados, provavelmente ao realizar a instalação do SQL Server Management Studio e do SQL, a instalação te deu 2 opções para realizar login no DB, a autenticação com windows ou a que você mesmo escolher,

exemplo:

Usuário: user1

Senha: 1234

No campo autenticação é possivel mudar a forma de login seja ela com autenticação do próprio windows caso você tenha escolhido ou a que você definiu através de um usuário e senha especifico